# Bash extended globbing brackets break array initalization

Tags: arrays, bash, glob

I used the statement `echo *([!min]).css` to get all filenames in the current directory with the **.css** extension, except for the ones with **.min.css** extension. That worked on the bash.

However, when I use this to initialize an array in a bash script like that

```
files=(*([!min]).css)
```

it doesn't work anymore. Bash says there is an unexpected opening bracket somewhere. My editor's syntax highlighting also looks like the brackets of the glob inside the array initialization are not correct, however I wasn't able to get it right.

Any advice? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I use GNU Bash 4.3.033 on ArchLinux.

Comment: `files=*([!min]).css` ?

Comment: @Cyrus No, same error.

Comment: files=$((*([!min]).css)) try this ??

Comment: @Cyrus: Pathname expansion is not performed on the RHS of (non-array) variable assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use [extended globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob), you must enable the extglob shell option. Put it at the start of your script, just below the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
#...
files=( !(*.min).css )
#...
```

Note that shell options are not inherited, so even though you may have extglob enabled in the interactive bash you run the script from, you still have to explicitly enable it in the script.

Comment: I already explained that the glob itself worked outside of the script in the bash, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @nsommer, that just means you have it enabled in your interactive session (probably by bash-completion). It's disabled by default, and that's why it doesn't work in your script.

Comment: Kudos for getting this right; I suggest you add the pitfall re `extglob` _potentially_ being enabled in _interactive_ shells due to initialization files, but not in _scripts_, to the answer itself.

Comment: @geirha Thanks for being so patient, looks like you're right. I actually did try enabling extglobs in the script before which didn't result in a correct execution. I guess it was a problem with the glob itself before, when using your example after the latest edit, everything works.